# Get ICollection data for many-to-many relationship in Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have struggling to get ICollection value in entity framework. I am using version 6.

[image]

### Class Navigation_Functions

```
[Table("Navigation_Functions")]
public class Navigation_Functions
{
    public Navigation_Functions()
    {}

    [Key]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Title")]
    [Display(Name = "Function Title")]
    public string FunctionName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Hierarchy Level")]
    [Display(Name = "Hierarchy Level")]
    public int Hierarchy_Level { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
}
```

### Class Navigation_Controller

```
[Table("Navigation_FunctionController")]
public class Navigation_FunctionController
{
    public Navigation_FunctionController()
    { }

    [Key]
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    [Required]
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Navigation_Functions> Navigation_Functions { get; set; }

}
```

### Middle Class to break many-to-many relationship

```
[Table("Navigation_FunctionInController")]
public class Navigation_FunctionInController
{
    public Navigation_FunctionInController() 
    { 

    }

    [Key]
    public int FunctionInController_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Navigation_Functions")]
    public int Function_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Navigation_FunctionController")]
    public int ControllerID { get; set; }

    public Navigation_FunctionController Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
    public Navigation_Functions Navigation_Functions { get; set; }

}
```

so when I run following code, I get all navigation_controller for navigation_function

```
    public IEnumerable<Navigation_Functions> GetAllFunctions()
    {
        using(var _uow = new FunctionsNavigation_UnitOfWork())
        {
            var entities = _uow.Navigation_Functions_Repository.GetAll();

            return entities.ToList();
        }
    }
```

I add virtual to model as

```
public virtual ICollection<Navigation_Functions> Navigation_Functions { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }
```

and I am getting following error to read data
[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i cannot get value in Icollection i.e. ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController

Comment: I have upload image in my question, refer above

Comment: Mark your collection as `virtual` or use `Include()` to eagerly load it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the many to many relationship table, Entity framework will do that for you. All you need is to declare your properties as virtual, all use the include method.
more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) or [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: do I need to use fluent API for that??

Comment: No yo don't need.remove Navigation_FunctionInController class, then use the virtual before   public virtual  ICollection<Navigation_FunctionController> Navigation_FunctionController { get; set; }

Comment: I still have no result, I remove middle class and add virtual, refer to screen shot I have updated in my question above

Comment: did you update your db? make sure that you EF created the many to many relationship table, make that you have data for the given id

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set ICollection method as "virtual"
e.g.
    public virtual ICollection Courses { get; set; }

Here is an example:
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Keep in mind if the intersection table contains one or more properties (which are not part of the Primary Key), then don't create an intersection table, just use to ICollection in both entities.  However, if there is one or more properties in the intersection, then create the intersection class. This is how the EF Designer works.